# Cannot remove item from Finder sidebar

Tags: finder, mojave

Note that [there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56491/i-cant-remove-items-from-the-sidebar-in-finder) are [other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155269/removing-items-from-finder-toolbar) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297802/folders-wont-remove-from-finder-sidebar-el-capitan-bug) on Ask Different with similar issues, but this appears to be different to those - none of the solutions offered in the above questions solve the issue.

I'm using macOS Mojave version 10.14.1 (18B75). In the past few days, 'Desktop' has appeared in my Favourites sidebar in Finder.

[image]

'Remove from Sidebar' is an option if I right-click the item:

[image]

If I click this, the item disappears for a fraction of a second, and then reappears.

The same thing happens if I try to remove the item in the Finder Preferences:

[image]

And, unlike [one solution offered on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297802/folders-wont-remove-from-finder-sidebar-el-capitan-bug), toggling my User folder in the Finder Preferences doesn't solve the issue.

How can I make Desktop disappear permanently?

Comment: Press F3 (Mission Control)  and see how many desktops you have

Comment: Just the one...

Comment: interesting, so you can make it go away but it comes back by it self ?

Comment: Just for fun, add it to Dock, then remove from Finder

Comment: Hold the Option key and right click on Finder in the Dock. New widow shows `Relaunch Finder`

Comment: @Ruskes no good – it still reappears even if I reboot Finder.

Comment: Is your home folder shared in any way (Google Drive, Dropbox…)?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Yes! My home folder is Microsoft OneDrive. The issue is with the Desktop shortcut, but I'm intrigued to know why the shared home folder might be relevant...

Comment: Because the sharing is introducing synchronization mechanisms which save the sidebar configuration file when the Finder which keep it open will save it too. And apparently the winner is… OneDrive. So you have to stop it a few seconds to stop this stupid write race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I'm not going to pretend I know what's happening here but try deleting the file where that info is stored:

```
$HOME/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2
```

I would bet that there's something corrupted in there.  Delete it, log out and log back in or reboot, and try to remove it again.  See if that helps.

Comment: Yep, we may not know *why* it happened, but this has fixed it. Thanks :)